# How to show a ViewController in your iOS app by only using Code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios-simulator

I want to show a ViewController in my app without using a storyboard entry point.

I made sure that the default storyboard entry point is deleted and that the storyboard id and name is correct. Still everything I get is just a black screen when running the app on the simulator.

Here is my AppDelegate.swift file.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC")


        window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()




        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Every kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit different with the `SceneDelegate` that with the application delegate. You use a `UIWindowScene` to construct your `UIWindow`.

```
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC")

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Viewcontrollers and xcode 11.3.1  or later, follow these steps after create new project.

1. Remove Application Scene Manifest from info.plist
   [image: info.plist]
2. Delete **SceneDelegate.swift** file
3. Remove Swift UI related methods from AppDelegate file.
4. Delete **ContentView.swift** file
5. Create new ViewController file
    File>New>Cocoa Touch Class
   [image: create new view controller]
6. set our MainViewController at AppDelegate file.

Add this

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   window!.rootViewController = MainViewController()
   window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
   window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
```